# Program will give an error if method not marked public ( all classes are in the same file)

Tags: java, private, public

I am trying to create an Anonymous class during which I came across following problem. In the following code when I change display method access modifier to default it gives an error but when I change it to public it works fine. Could you explain it to me why this happens.AFAIK public and default are work in similar as long as all classes are in same package. Please correct me if I am wrong.

---

//from file : Skg.java

```
package sandeep2;

class Skg1 
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("sandeep here");
    }
}

class Skg2 {

    public void say()
    {
        System.out.println("Skg2");
    }

    Skg1 obj = new Skg1()  
    {
        **public void display()**  //wont work if this is not public ????????????
        {
            System.out.println("I am ANONymous");
        }
    };
}

public class Skg {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Skg2 x = new Skg2();
        x.obj.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Skg2` attempts to create an instance of an anonymous inner class as a subclass of class `Skg1`.  That anonymous inner class overrides `Skg1.display()`, which is public.  You cannot override a method to reduce its visibility.  Java does not permit it, and it would violate the substitution principle if you could do it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you redefine a method to be _more_ visible? (e.g. `private` > `public`)

Comment: @Arc676, yes, you can override a method to make it more visible, for instance from default to public.  `private` methods are not virtual, however.  A subclass can provide a method with the same name and signature as a superclass's `private` method, but that's not an override -- the superclass's calls to its private method will not be dynamically dispatched to your alternative version.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response. I didn't know that. Looks like I need to read more about overriding. Thanks a ton, again.